# Find if given number is prime or not

Tags: c, primes

I am trying to find if **5915587277** is prime or not.
This number is actually prime and I am expecting this from my program.
When I run this program it says that it is not prime and its divisor is 199.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long n = 0;
    long i = 0;
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    long m = n/2;

    if(n%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Not Prime");
        return 0;
    }

    for( i = 3; i <= m; i++)
    {
        if(n%i == 0)
        {
            printf("Not Prime: %d\n", i);
            return 0;
        }

    }

    printf("Prime");
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why this code is printing this number as NOT prime when it is.

Comment: OK, so what's your question?

Comment: It works for me, says it's a prime. But I'm on 64-bit architecture. Also, your `for` loops increment condition should be `i+=2`, first it's quicker; second, if you increment by 1 then your previous `if` makes little sense.

Comment: Read more about [primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). It is a difficult issue.

Comment: 5915587277 - 2^32 = 1620619981 = 199 * 8143819

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are exceeding the max value for a long. See [Data type limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).

Comment: Refer to the link I posted, please.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the program... when ran on linux box.. i receive 5915587277 as prime

Comment: I am running this program on 32-bit Windows 7

Comment: From the related link: `LLONG_MAX` = 9223372036854775807, so yes, `long long int` solves your problem

Comment: @AlterMann This is the value I have for `long int`. But I'm on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: @AntonH the limits provided in the link are minimums required by the standard. In fact, an implementation may decided that `short` is also 64 bits.

Comment: @AntonH, if in doubt use `limits.h`, run this code on your computer http://ideone.com/RxEWvV

Answer (score 0):

Which type of compiler you are using? if it supports 64 bit numbers then you can do that. Another thing is that use the unsigned long integer to store the maximum value. your code is just fine but you need to brush up your knowledge in max value can be stored by particular data type.
    Hope this answer may help you.

Comment: Windows supports 64-bit numbers, but `long` is still 32-bit.